# parent() next() selectors and scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have several articles which scroll when clicking on more or when clicking on less. The position should be any given element after the article (such as br or div), but i get problems refering to this one. Is it possible to use the parent and next selectors or should i make auxiliary divs to scroll to them?

html:

```
<div id="text1">
<p>Text   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="more">More..</a><p>
<div id="more">more text   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="less">Less..</a></div>
</div> <br>

<div id="text2">
<p>Text <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="more2">More..</a><p>
<div id="more2">more text    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="less2">Less..</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#more").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div").find("#more").slideDown("slow"); 

       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parents("div").next().offset().top
        }, 1000);
});

$("#less").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("#more").slideUp("slow");
});


    $("#more2").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div").find("#more2").slideDown("slow");    

       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parents("div").next().offset().top
        }, 1000);
});

$("#less2").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("#more2").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: First, element `id`s must be unique. Use classes instead. Fix that, and see where it gets you.

Comment: By definition or as a general advise? i've used the same ids on purpose so that it was the same case for all the articles

Comment: anyways, i've just tried and it still doesn't scroll

Comment: The html specification says they must be unique. Additionally, jQuery id selectors will only ever return one element, so you'll run into problems there.

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/XWKMu/

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, if you put your answer in the other part i upvote you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`'id'` must be unique within the HTML document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). You just need to change your 'more' and 'less' to a class so you can bind the same event handler and execution on them.

```
<div id="text1">
    <p>Text <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">More..</a>

    </p>
    <div class="more-text">more text 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="less">Less..</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="text2">
    <p>Text <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="more">More..</a>

    </p>
    <div class="more-text">more text 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="less">Less..</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.more').click(function () {
    var $more_text = $(this).parents('div').find('.more-text');

    $more_text.slideDown('slow');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $more_text.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});

$('.less').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.more-text').slideUp('slow');
});
```

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/977tH/).